# Mobius function for reflection subgroups

Tags: co.combinatorics, mobius-inversion

Let $W$ be a finite real reflection group. Let $\Pi(W)$ be the set of reflection subgroups of $W$. Then $\Pi(W)$ has a natural partial order defined by inclusion. Let $\mu$ denote the associated Mobius function.

Question: Does there exists some sort of an explicit expression for $\mu$?

In Type $A$, i.e. when $W=S_n$, then $\Pi(W)$ identifies with the poset of set-partitions of $\{1,2,...,n\}$. In this case, the Mobius function is given explicitly in, e.g., Stanley's book. What happens in other types?

Comment: Do you not just get the lattice of flats of the arrangements of reflecting hyperplanes in general?

Comment: Perhaps. Unfortunately, I don't know what "lattice of flats of the arrangments of reflecting hyperplane means". If you provide some references that would be great.

Comment: Well, if by "Stanley's book" above you mean Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. 1 then in Chapter 3 he does discuss hyperplane arrangements and their lattices of flats (and geometric lattices more generally); more in depth notes about hyperplane arrangements from Stanley are https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf.

Comment: @SamHopkins No, that is for praabolic subgroups. There are more reflection subgroups (such as A1xA1 in B2).

Comment: @ChristianStump: Interesting! Then I will 2nd Dr. Evil's request: do you have a good reference for the poset of reflection subgroups?

Comment: The isomorphism types of reflection subgroups are known and a student of mine computed their counting numbers by type some time ago. I have not seen that poset being considered. (I am out of office this week, will try to look into this again when I am back and provide a reference for the occurring types.)